# Nested RewriteRules on Apache 2.4 causing 500 errors

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site running on cPanel, where wordpress is installed in the root.  I also have a custom application I have written which is located in a subfolder named 'gallery'.  Within the gallery subfolder is an 'admin' folder.  The root folder of gallery (no rewrite) controls the display of information, where the root of 'gallery/admin' grants the user administrative access to the application. The path structure is redirected and handled (custom MVC framework), which is primarily directed by the following .htaccess directives :

Require all granted

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|bmp|gif|css|js|map|ttf|woff|woff2|svg|eot)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller.php?page=error&rewritten=1&missing=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The .htaccess for wordpress is customized for compression, expiring/caching of different types, in addition to handling traditional wordpress stuff and is as follows (pasting in full) :

```
Options -Indexes
# BEGIN WordPress

# Expires Caching (Leverage Browser Caching)
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 2 week"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 week"
</IfModule>

# Enable GZIP Compression (compress text, html, javascript, css, xml and so on) ##
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.org
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml /sitemap.php?p=xml [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xsl /sitemap.php?p=xsl [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.css /sitemap.php?p=css [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.js /sitemap.php?p=js [L]
RewriteRule ^robots.txt /sitemap.php?p=txt [L]
RewriteRule ^gallery - [L]
RewriteRule ^controller\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The reason behind the double check `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` was because of another issue I had when trying to handle only files of a specific type where the file does not exist physically. (pretty 404 not found page when jpg/etc are missing).

As you can see, `controller.php` does all the grunt work for authentication, etc. If I comment out any of the lines containing `^(.*)$ controller.php?` I don't get 500 errors unless I call the controller directly and let it redirect based on the application root path.

This works flawlessly on my Debian 8, and Ubuntu 11 boxes, as well as on Windows 10. The admin is based on the open source project [otp-thing](https://github.com/microvb/otp-thing) and works well. Just am having some trouble handling the redirects when the almighty wordpress is in the root of the site.

There doesn't appear to be any code issues (if so, they would have cropped up in other tests on Debian 8, Ubuntu 11, and especially Windows 10).

The server software running on this build of cPanel are as follows :

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)
Server built:   Mar  1 2016 10:43:46
Cpanel::Easy::Apache v3.32.10 rev9999
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:52
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses disabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr/local/apache"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/local/apache/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

And PHP

```
PHP 5.6.18 (cli) (built: Mar  1 2016 10:47:52) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.7.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

Also, if you look at the project source for otp-thing, you will notice some of the nested directories intentionally block public access (app/cache, app/templates_c, etc)

The error that is reported by Apache in `/usr/local/apache/error_log` is :

> [Thu Aug 25 21:33:21.323468 2016] [core:error] [pid 15805] [client XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXXX] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

**The message is identical if I comment out any combination of the `RewriteRule` lines from the `gallery/admin/.htaccess` file.**

I have tried adding had paths preceding 'controller.php', however this exacerbates the problem, but overall, no change to the issue at hand here.

What can I do to make sure that all this stuff works, or even as a workaround, how can I move the htaccess rules for otp-thing into the wordpress htaccess file as above by merging them (how can the directives be adjusted).

Comment: Rule of thumb: when you get a 500, your FIRST stop is to check the apache error log for details. Anything else is pointless - until you know WHAT the problem is, there's no point in randomly stabbing around in the dark.

Comment: @MarcB - Sorry, I should have posted that information.  The apache log is non-specific and as this is cPanel, complex to adjust it for more information. Adding the message above

Comment: @MarcB - also, my first stop is enabling php error output -- then apache logs, as often a lot of errors show in php as 500 errors ( missing squiggly brace, etc ), if php error reporting/display is set to "production" values -- esp in php-fpm/etc environments.

Comment: Add `RewriteRule ^controller\.php - [L,NC]` rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line

Comment: @anubhava - If I place that there, it will prevent redirecting from non-www to www.  After that check, I already have it excluded. I do not have the NC flag tho, so I will try that.  (assuming this directive in my wordpress .htaccess file) - also, I am using the `$` terminator, however I did have `^gallery` which in theory should exclude the whole directory and all contents.

Comment: No, not in WP .htaccess but in the other .htaccess shown at start of your question.

Comment: @anubhava - That just excludes the whole script from working, and I additionally get DirectoryIndex missing error (since there is no index.html, index.php, etc) in that folder.  The first .htaccess is in `/gallery/admin/`  --- I have no idea why -- but that worked.  Doesn't that directive mean to exclude ??  (voted up)

Comment: Where does `controller.php` exist and what is exact URL you're using to test this?

Comment: @anubhava - `controller.php` is located in `/gallery/admin/` and handles all page requests where any filtered type of file doesn't exist (images not found physically), as well as acts as the controller for handling the MVC framework for each page requested.   Your solution which I upvoted worked for me, although it is still unclear why as I thought`^` followed by ` - [L]` meant exclude, and having that first seems it would exclude it completely from processing.  But it works.  Could you explain why  ?

Comment: ok I've added an answer below with modified version of `/gallery/admin/.htaccess`. I've added comments above each rule to make it clear. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in `/gallery/admin/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewrtieBase /gallery/admin/

# skip any rule below this for controller.php or for valid files / directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /controller\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# rewrite all except certain static resource extensions to controller.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|png|bmp|gif|css|js|map|ttf|woff|woff2|svg|eot)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ controller.php?page=$0 [L,QSA]

# rewrite not found static resource extensions
RewriteRule ^.*$ controller.php?page=error&rewritten=1&missing=$0 [L,QSA]
```